# Let A,B be languages. If A is decidable and B undecidable, then A reducible to B

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

So I'm learning for an upcoming exam and there's a specific problem which I can't show:

> Let A be decidable and B undecidable, then $A \le B$

Can someone give me a hint how to solve that? Furthermore, does that mean, that every decidable language is reducible to an undecidable language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is that your reduction can compute any computable function of its input. Whether an instance of $A$ is a "yes" or a "no" instance is computable by construction.

And, yes, that means that every decidable language is reducible to every undecidable language.  It means that because you've assumed nothing about $A$ and $B$ except decidability of $A$ and undecidability of $B$.

Comment: does that mean, that I have to construct a function to prove this property? how do I include the undecidability of B in such a function?

Comment: You don't need to include the undecidability of $B$. Actually, it doesn't matter if $B$ is undecidable or not: all you need is that $B\neq\emptyset$ and $B\neq\Sigma^*$, which is guaranteed if $B$ is undecidable.

Comment: ok, I think I've understood: since A is decidable, there is a function f*, that can decide whether w is in A or not. my function should be simply: function(w): if f* accepts w then accept w; else reject w; end function // thanks for your hints and I hope this is right

Comment: @but_they_should No, that just reduces $A$ to itself. Your function needs to take an instance of $A$ and produce a "yes" instance of $B$ if $f$ accepts $A$ and a "no" instance otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand, I guess a pseudo code would help me. I tried to formulate it myself based on your comment, but it's a mess. What is $f$? Is that my reduction or my function to construct? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @but_they_should Sorry -- I changed your notation.  My function $f$ is the same as your $f^*$. The argument is that, since $A$ is decidable, there's a computable function $f^*$ that determines whether its input is a member of $A$. To reduce $A$ to $B$, you need a map $g$ from inputs to $A$ to inputs to $B$ such that $x\in A$ iff $g(x)\in B$. So you define $g$ by picking $y\in B$ and $z\notin B$ and saying that $g(x)=y$ if $f^*$ says that $x\in A$ and $g(x)=z$ otherwise.

Comment: Ok, now it's obvious to me why $B$ is needlessly premised to be undecidable. Again, thanks for clarification and your time!